# Go Back and resubmit form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have added a back button to a search result page, with a link of:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.reload(history.go(-1))">Back to seach results!</a>
```

But as this is being used with a form I am being met with a form resubmit page when using chrome, or an alert asking me to resubmit when using IE.

Is there and simple way to force the page to reload so the end user isn't met with either the screen or pop-up

Edit: I am using PHP so if there is a way of using PHP that would be okay too.

Comment: No there's no way to prevent that alert. The reason is because the previous page was generated via a form submission, so to return to the page in that state the form submission has to occur again, hence the warning. The alternative would be to store the form parameters and have the back button resubmit the form manually.

Comment: Ahh okay, I guess it will have to stay as it is for now then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No there's no way to prevent that alert. The reason is because the previous page was generated via a form submission, so to return to the page in that state the form submission has to occur again, hence the warning. The alternative would be to store the form parameters and have the back button resubmit the form manually"

Credit to Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Add this to the page that has the 'Confirm Resubmit' popup

```
<script>
if(window.history.replaceState) { 
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href ); 

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you are returning search results, which typically use get requests. As far as I'm aware, that warning isn't present if you make your form `method="get"`